# Eclipse throwing errors for maven compile phase?

Tags: pom.xml

Projects are not able to execute two life cycle phases of maven life cycle mapping:

1. compiler:compile
2. compiler: testcompile

Following are errors in eclipse:

1. > CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
   >   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its
   >   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
   >   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1:
   >   ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
   >   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from
   >   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
   >   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
   >   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
   >   Could not transfer artifact
   >   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to
   >   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
   >   pom.xml                /ex         line 1     Maven Project Build
   >   Lifecycle Mapping Problem
2. > Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
   >   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile
   >   (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)           pom.xml
   >   /ex         line 1     Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
3. > Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
   >   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile
   >   (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
   >   pom.xml              /ex         line 1              Maven Project
   >   Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In eclipse goto windows->preferences->maven->user setting

point user settings textbox to setting.xml in %M2_HOME%\conf

Answer (score 0):

```
if its not working still then you need to add plugins in the POM.xml and update project

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                     <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                     </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```